# Scrollable Card Stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-listview

I want to create a scrollable card stack. I want the back one to disappear and the front one to disappear when I slide what is seen in the photo, how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: How exactly should it scroll? like you said you want both the back and the front to disappear? Please explain better? What kinds of gestures should achieve what kinds of movements in your stack? or should gestures on the stack shift the entire stack position (scrolling)?

Comment: We can think of it like a slider. When you swipe, you need to switch to the other cart.

Comment: switch to the other cart? like make the image on top go behind? and bring the image under the on top?

Comment: Yes, excatly...

Comment: okay give me some time to write the code, test it and post as answer for you.

Comment: OK, I'm waiting. Thanks

Comment: Please let's continue the discussion in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242576/discussion-between-obumuneme-nwabude-and-volkanustekidag)

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work.

On tapping/clicking anywhere the cards should change position with the topmost card going to the back.

Changing `_spacing`'s value changes the relative horizontal and vertical gaps among the cards in the stack.

Note that the members of the `_colors` list are in reverse order. This is because, with [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html), widgets are displayed on top of each other based on the last widgets that were added to the `children` list. This also explains why the call back to `setState` makes the last member of the `_colors` list to become the first member instead.

```dart
class StackSwipe extends StatefulWidget {
  const StackSwipe({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StackSwipe> createState() => _StackSwipeState();
}

class _StackSwipeState extends State<StackSwipe> {
  final double _spacing = 16.0;
  late double _baseWidth;
  final _colors = [
    Colors.greenAccent.shade100,
    Colors.pink.shade100,
    Colors.amber.shade100,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    _baseWidth = deviceWidth > 544 ? 512.0 : deviceWidth - 32;

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Stack(children: [
          ..._colors.asMap().entries.map(
                (entry) => Positioned(
                  top: _spacing * entry.key,
                  left: _spacing * (_colors.length - (entry.key + 1)),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: _baseWidth -
                        (_spacing * (_colors.length - (entry.key + 1)) * 2),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      color: entry.value,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
        ]),
        onTap: () => setState(() => _colors.insert(0, _colors.removeLast())),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```